# How to visualize (value, count) dataset with thousands data points

Tags: r

I have a file with 2 numeric columns: value and count. File may have > 5000 rows. I do `plot(value, count)` to find the shape of distribution. But because there are too many data points the picture is not very clear.

Do you know better visualization approach? Probably histograms or barplot with grouping close values on x axis will be the better way to look on data? I cannot figure out the syntax of using histogram or barplot for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to relate the two (continuous) quantities `value` and `count` to each other, then you want to do a scatterplot. The problem is that if you have too many observations, the points will overlap and the plot ends up as a big opaque mass with a few scattered outliers. There are a couple of ways to solve this:

- Use a smaller plotting symbol: `plot(value, count, pch=".")`
- Plot the data points with a transparency factor: `plot(value, count, col=rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.1))`

Answer (score 0):

Why not plot a subset of the data?  For example, plot the counts associated with values corresponding to the 5th, 10th, ..., 90th, 95th percentiles, e.g.,

```
value.subset <- quantile(value, seq(0, 1, 0.05))plot
```

Then plot the quantiles against their respective counts.